# How to get response header from reverse proxy

Tags: go

How can I detect and react on a response header from within a reverse proxy?

I'm writing a middleware method which is injected into a reverse proxy. I confirmed the middleware is being called.

The server sets a response header `X-SERVER-VAR` with a value of `Foo`. I need to detect and run some code based on the value.

I thought I'd read the ResponseWriter, thinking the server response should include the value, but nothing is logging.

```
func SessionHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf(w.Header().Get("X-SERVER-VAR"))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I'm using `github.com/gorilla/mux` to attach this middleware handler.

I'm setting everything up with code similar to below (simplified for this question).

```
func newProxy(remote string) http.Handler {
    proxyurl, err := url.Parse(remote)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(proxyurl)
    return proxy
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Use(SessionHandler)
    proxy := newProxy("https://www.example.com/")
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(proxy)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9001", r))
}
```

If it isn't possible with middleware, is it possible to detect a response header from the server another way?

Comment: Hmm any chance you need to use the `r` object rather than `w`? I think `w` is the response you'll return to the request you have.

Comment: If the code in your question is truly representative (i.e the only omitted logic is in the `...`) then that is your problem: You're checking for the header before calling `next()`, so the remote server hasn't been consulted yet.

Comment: @Flimzy I think you are answering my question here. Yes, that is the only relevant code to my question, except next(). It's the handler for middleware I attach with Gorilla mux via .Use().

That means part of the answer is that I cannot do this with a middleware pattern (thank you!)  but the broader question is how, where, or if I can operate on a response header sent by the server.

Comment: Why do you think middleware won't work here?  You would just do the log after instead of before: `next.ServeHTTP(w, r) log.Printf(w.Header().Get("X-SERVER-VAR"))`

Comment: Why can't you do this as middleware?

Comment: I misinterpreted the information. I'm new to Go and working with a proxy at this level. I am excited to give the suggestions a try tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to read the response headers before they're set.

Change this:

```golang
func SessionHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf(w.Header().Get("X-SERVER-VAR"))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

To this:

```golang
func SessionHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Printf(w.Header().Get("X-SERVER-VAR"))
    })
}
```